# Passing string literals to functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When you assign a string literal such as "ABC" to char a[] ex.

```
char a[] = "ABC";
```

it has the effect of doing

```
char a[4] = {'A','B','C','0'};
```

does this same thing apply when you pass it to a function parameter

ex.

```
int f(char a[]);
```

vs.

```
int f(char *a);
```

Comment: `"ABC"` is a `char [4]` not a `char [3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does this same thing apply when you pass it to a function parameter

No; in general, in C you can't pass arrays directly by value; every array parameter to a function is actually interpreted by the compiler as a pointer parameter, i.e. when you write

```
int f(char a[]);
```

the compiler sees

```
int f(char *a);
```

(the same applies even if you specify the dimensions of the array)

---

By the way,

> it has the effect of doing
>
> ```
> char a[3] = {'A','B','C"};
> ```

Actually, it has the effect of doing:

```
char a[4] = {'A','B','C', 0};
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because both of those function declarations are identical. Both declare a function that takes a pointer to `char`, and in both cases the argument becomes initialised with a pointer to the first element of the string literal.

Comment: You mean of the string, not of the string literal.